# Windows Forms Hidden Panel with buttons is still active

Tags: c#, winforms

First, I have to use windows forms I know it is bad for making games, but its for school.

I have designed a pause menu for my game using a panel with buttons on it. Here is the code for When I press escape to open the pause menu.

```cs
private void Game_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
    {
        if (paused == true)
        {
            paused = false;
            pnlPaused.Visible = false;
            tmrAnimations.Start();
            tmrGame.Start();
            tmrJump.Start();
            tmrPlayerMovement.Start();
            tmrLeftMovement.Start();
            tmrRightMovement.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            pnlPaused.BringToFront();
            pnlPaused.Visible = true;
            pnlPaused.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(80, 79, 249, 249);
            paused = true;
            tmrAnimations.Stop();
            tmrGame.Stop();
            tmrJump.Stop();
            tmrPlayerMovement.Stop();
            tmrLeftMovement.Stop();
            tmrRightMovement.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

This code works fine until I click one of the buttons. When any button is clicked, even the ones with no code, it is impossible to press escape to unpause again. With this resume button the timers all start and the game starts working again but the form doesn't register any key clicks.

```cs
private void btnResume_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    paused = false;
    pnlPaused.Visible = false;
    tmrAnimations.Start();
    tmrGame.Start();
    tmrJump.Start();
    tmrPlayerMovement.Start();
    tmrLeftMovement.Start();
    tmrRightMovement.Start();
}
```

I have tried adding this code into the button click code

```
pnlPaused.Enabled = false;
```

This code works in re-enabling user input but every time a key is pressed the windows error sound plays, the one when you have to dismiss an alert etc but try clicking off (hopefully that makes sense). Does anyone know another way to fix the panel still being active after being hidden or preventing the windows sound?

Answer (score 0):

I have realized all I needed to do was unfocus the button with

```
this.Focus();
```